# Applying Ascoli's theorem to the space of continuous cumulative distribution functions

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show that the space of continuous,strictly increasing commutative distribution functions are relatively compact. Though, I am not sure if I can do this.

Firstly, I consider the space of continuous, strictly increasing cumulative distribution functions on a compact interval $E_1$. Then, by Ascoli's theorem, this space is relatively compact. Now, I apply Ascoli's theorem again on a compact interval $E_2\supset E_1$, and so on, $E_n\supset E_{n-1}$.

The space of strictly increasing, continuous cumulative distribution functions on $E_n$ is relatively compact for all $n$. Hence this space is relatively compact on $\mathbb{R}$.

Can I make such an argument?

Answer (score 1):

No. First Arzela's theorem requires the compactness; localizing as you suggest results in uniform convergence on compact subsets which is not really what you want. More to the point, the local result fails too because equicontinuity fails under these assumptions. Consider $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1]$ and extended to be $0$ on the left and $1$ on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F_n$ be normal with mean $0$ and variance $n$. Then there is no convergent subsequence.